# extract specific part of JSON file and save it in a separate JSON file using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to extract `dependencies` part of my package.json and save it in a separate JSON file, using gulp. My package JSON looks as following:

```
{
  "name": "my-json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my-json for test",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/"
  ],
  "scripts": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "ms-signalr-client": "2.2.5",
    "ng2-translate": "^1.11.1",
    "numeral": "1.5.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.18",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-chmod": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.10.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.20",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.24",
    "live-server": "^0.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "traceur": "^0.0.91",
    "tslint": "3.9.0",
    "yargs": "^4.7.1"
  }
}
```

I need only `dependencies` and need to create and save it in separate JSON with the structure something like:

```
{
 "dependencies" : [
   {
     "name": "angular2",
     "key": "2.0.0-beta.15"
   },
   ...
 ]
}
```

I have tried `npm list -json --depth=0 > dependencies.json`, but it is not really what I want. It adds many unneeded lines. I just start to get familiar with gulp.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you know how to access a property of a JavaScript object?

Comment: I know that I can do `var fs = require('fs');

var json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./package.json'));` but do not know how to extract only `"dependencies{..}"` and then save it in a format I would like to...

Comment: Node can actually load JSON files and parses them for your: `var deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;`. Then you stringify that object and write it back to disk: `fs.writeFileSync('./deps.json', JSON.stringify({dependencies: deps}));`.

Comment: yep, this does the work, But this creates: `{ "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15", ...}` but how to separate "angular2" and "2.0.0-beta.15" and create `{ "name":"2.0.0-beta.15", "key": "2.0.0-beta.15"}, {..}

Comment: Create an array, iterate over the original object and add a new object with the desired structure for each property. Then write the array to disk.